# change content with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the content of  if it exists.

I am trying to get with `getElementsByClassName` and modifying with `innerHTML`.

```js
function drink() {
    const spans=document.getElementsByClassName('.minimal-price-link span.price-label').innerHtml = 'Only';
    for(let i=0;i<spans.length;i++) {
        const span=spans[i];                        
    }
    return null;
}
drink();
```

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com" class="minimal-price-link"><span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee"> <span class="price-label">From</span> <span id="3048" data-price-amount="6.9" data-price-type="" class="price-wrapper ">$6,90</span></span></a>
```

returns `null` but does not change.

Comment: why  `const span=spans[i];                        }
        return null;` ?

Comment: you can shorten `const spans=document.getElementsByClassName('.minimal-price-link span.price-label').innerHtml = 'Only';` to `const spans = 'Only';` the part in between has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query elements like you would in CSS, use `querySelectorAll`, and change the `innerText` (not `innerHtml`, which is really `innerHTML`) in the loop (and there is no need to return `null`, or anything, if you're not going to use it somewhere):

```js
function drink() {
  const spans = document.querySelectorAll('.minimal-price-link span.price-label');
  for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].innerText = 'Apenas';
  }
}
drink();
```

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com" class="minimal-price-link"><span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee"> <span class="price-label">From</span> <span id="3048" data-price-amount="6.9" data-price-type="" class="price-wrapper ">$6,90</span></span></a>
```